# Access violation when calling IMG_Load_RW() over a binary stringstream?

Tags: c++, sdl, access-violation, stringstream, sdl-image

I have created some encrypted jpg images by reading them byte by byte, adding a value 3 to each byte and sending the manipulated bytes back to a filestream. The program can also decrypt them to their original file by doing the reverse operation (subtracting the number 3) and it all works fine.

Now I want to read an encrypted jpg image into a binary stringstream, decrypt it and then create an SDL Surface directly from that jpg stringstream memory data.

This is the function I wrote:

```cpp
bool b_get_SDLSurface_from_stream(string str_path, SDL_Surface** sdls_image)
{
    ifstream ifstr_i;
    stringstream ss_image_data(stringstream::out | stringstream::binary);
    unsigned char  uint8_b;

    ifstr_i.open(str_path.c_str(), std::ios_base::binary);
    if (!ifstr_i.is_open())
    {
        return false;
    }

    while (ifstr_i >> noskipws >> uint8_b)
    {
        uint8_b = uint8_b - 3;                                                                
        ss_image_data << uint8_b;
    }

    if (ss_do.rdbuf()->in_avail() == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    int n_size = ss_image_data.str().size();
    SDL_RWops* p_sdlrwops_image = SDL_RWFromMem(&ss_image_data, n_size);

    if (p_sdlrwops_i == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    *sdls_image = IMG_Load_RW(p_sdlrwops_image, 0);
    if (*sdls_image == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    ifstr_i.close();
    return true;
}
```

...but I get an error saying there is an access violation at the point where the following line is called:

```cpp
*sdls_image = IMG_Load_RW(p_sdlrwops_image, 0);
```

Comment: `SDL_Surface** sdls_image` -- `*sdls_image = IMG_Load_RW(p_sdlrwops_image, 0);` -- We have no idea, when, where, or how `sdls_image` is allocated, used, etc. before you use it here.

Comment: Why are you creating a `SDL_RWops` from `ss_image_data` and not the data inside `ss_image_data().str()`?

Comment: `&ss_image_data` is a pointer to string stream object, not to the data it holds. It would be a better idea store data in `vector<uint8_t>` instead of string stream.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the SDL surface is a member of a class. The address of the surface is passed to the function described above. If i load the surface from a file it works fine.

Comment: @genpfault Thank you, I have now tried to use `string s = ss_image_data.str()` and then  `const char* c = s.c_str()` and `int n_size = s.size()`. I then used `SDL_RWops* p_sdlrwops_image = SDL_RWFromMem(&c, n_size)`, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: @user7860670 This brought me to the solution. Would you like to write the answer so I can accept it? I still wonder if it would have been possible with the stringstream as well.
I used: `vector <unsigned char> v`, then in the decryption loop i used `v.push_back(uch)` with uch being the unsigned char variable instead of uint8_b and then i used `SDL_RWops* p_sdlrwops_i = SDL_RWFromMem(&v[0], v.size())`
very happy, thank you so much